# How do I change privacy of multiple photos on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

How do I change privacy settings of multiple photos on Facebook at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

Except for the **Wall Photos** and **Mobile Uploads** albums, the privacy settings are per album. Only for the two mentioned above you can change the privacy on a per photo basis.

So, for any album except **Wall Photos** and **Mobile Uploads**, *multiple photos* means entire album, while for those two means one by one.

From [How do I edit the privacy settings for my photo albums?](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=215496745135618)